# RPi + Adafruit Servo shield to control Brush motor and servo(steering) of a RC car!

Tags: pi-3, servo

I need help for my setup: I am not sure what I am doing wrong, but I just burned the servo-motor (for steering) of my RC car.

Here is my set up: [the rc car with brush motor and ESC](http://www.exceedrc.com/51c809-carbonblue-24ghz.html), RPi 3, [servo shield](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1411). The RPi and the servo-shield are powered from the same external USB battery (out=5V DC): I use a USB to 2X micro USB, and an adapter for the servo hat.

The 3-wire (black-red-white) cable out of the ESC is disconnected from the radio controller, and connected to the servo shield on channel 0. Note that I only connect the black (ground) and the white (signal) wires to channel0, with jumper cables. The red wire is not connected because the servo-hat is already powered by the USB battery.
The servo-motor that controls the steering is connected to the channel 4 of the servo-shield. The black/white/red wires are connected to the 3 pins on channel4, with the black wire towards the outer of the servo-hat board and the white wire towards the inner.

I wrote a little program (in python) to control the car with a GameSir gamepad: the left joystick controls the throttle, and the right joystick for steering. First, I tested the code with the motor/throttle only (the cable from the steering servo-motor was disconnected off channel 4 on the servo shield)- that part worked , I could control the speed of the motor with the gamepad. Then, I connected the steering cable to channel4 (the throttle cable is still connected to channel 0). As soon as I started moving the joystick that controls the steering, the raspberry pi rebooted. Later, I reconnected the cables to the radio controller: only the throttle works. The servo-motor for steering does not move nor make any sound.

Let me know if you have any suggestion!

Comment: I'm going to guess that the steering motor is an ordinary DC motor, rated for a couple of volts, not a servo at all.

Comment: Here is the model of the steering motor on the RC car: https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00CHI6ML4/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1. It is a servo-motor

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi SE.  Be sure to take the tour to see how this works and to earn a badge:  https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/Tour